# video file upload

Tags: video, file-upload

What is a good file size limit to use when allowing users to upload video.  I am not worried about bandwidth I just don't want users trying to upload files and getting server timeout errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it depends on your software, but in general as long as the server is receiving data it will not time out.  Timeouts usually occur when data stops comming in.

Answer (score 1):

But PHP stops execution when the upload file size exceeds the Max Allowed File Size and shows and Time Out Error.